# Carousel de Buef

Tags: vue.js, buefy

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola Actualmente tengo un carrusel de Buefy,
Inicialmente esta mostrando de 3 en 3 las fotos.
Quisiera que muestre de 3 en 3 en la primera carga y al momento de darle click en la flecha me muestre el resto que serian 2 fotos mas.

O bien que al darle click me lleve a la foto 4, actualmente me esta mostrando una por una

He leido la documentacion pero no hago que funcione.
Algun consejo?

```
 <div id="app" class="carrusel">
            <!-- Buefy components goes here -->
            <template>
                <b-carousel-list v-model="test" :data="items" :items-to-show="3">   
                    <template slot="item" slot-scope="props">
                        <div class="card redondo">
                            <div class="card-image">
                                <figure class="image is-5by4">
                                    <a @click="info(props.index)"><img :src="props.list.image" class="imagen-redondo"></a>
                                </figure>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <p class="Laboratorio-Centro2" >{{ props.list.title }}</p>
                                    <div class="boton-plus2"> <img src="./css/img_/icon-more.png" @click="isCardModalActive = true"class="plus2">
                                    
                                    </div>
                                    <img src="img/location.png" class="location">
    
                                    <p class="Av-9-de-Octubre-170">{{ props.list.subtitle}}</p>
      
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                        </div>
 new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data() {
                return {
                    isImageModalActive: false,
                    isCardModalActive: false,
                    test: 0,
                    testo: 0,
                    items: [{

                        title: 'Laboratorio Centro',
                        image: './img/edificios_asimed2.jpg',
                        subtitle: 'Av. 9 de Octubre 1703 y Av. del Ejercito, Piso 2 Oficina 10 Altos Bco. Pacifico',

                    }, {
                        title: 'Edificio ASIMED',
                        image: './img/edificios_asimed3.jpg',
                        subtitle: 'Kennedy Norte Avenida Miguel H.Alcivar Mz.408 Sl.2'
                    }, {
                        title: 'Medical Plaza',
                        image: './img/edificios_asimed4 (1).jpg',
                        subtitle: 'Avenida José Santiago Castillo, Mz. 601 Sl. 20/21 Of.104, Guayaquil.'
                    }, {
                        title: 'SUR',
                        image: './img/edificios_asimed5.jpg',
                        subtitle: 'Argentina 802 y Lorenzo de Garaycoa, (esq) Mezz.'
                    }, {
                        title: 'Medical Plaza',
                        image: './img/edificios_asimed5.jpg',
                        subtitle: 'Avenida José Santiago Castillo, Mz. 601 Sl. 20/21 Of.104, Guayaquil.'

                    }, ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Fijate el atributo `:items-to-list`. Creo que eso es lo que buscas.
Si le doy el valor 3, me muestra de a 3 items cuando hago click en la flecha.
Te quedaría así en tu ejemplo:

```
<b-carousel-list v-model="test" :data="items" :items-to-show="3" :items-to-list="3">
```

Comment: muchas gracias!

Comment: Disculpa estoy intentando cambiar el tamaño de las flechas: :icon-size="tamano">  y en el script  tamano = "" is-large", pero no funciona, algun consejo?

Comment: Podes usar icon-size sin los dos puntos delante del nombre. Te queda icon-size="is-large".

Comment: Si te fijas en la documentación, (https://buefy.org/documentation/carousel#api-view) en la tabla fijate que el tipo de propiedad sea String. Si la propiedad es de tipo String podes usarla sin los dos puntos antes del nombre. Esto es igual para todos los componentes.